# Organise .arb files in flutter using Flutter intl extension

Tags: flutter, localization, flutter-localizations, flutter-intl, arb

Running `Flutter Intl: Initialize` generates `lib/l10n/intl_en.arb`. However due to many strings in my applications I would wish to have multiple arb files for same language.

To make it more clear, consider the following folder structure

```
 -->lib
    --> screens
        --> screen_a.dart
        --> screen_b.dart
```

Correspondingly I would have my `l10n` folder structure as follows:

```
--> l10n
   --> screen_a
       --> intl_en.dart
       --> intl_fr_FR.dart
   --> screen_b
       --> intl_en.dart
       --> intl_fr_FR.dart
```

How do I achieve this using flutter intl plugin? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you found a good implementation of organizing .arb files? I am looking into this too.

Comment: Someone filed a feature request in the flutter repo https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/107157

Answer (score 3):

Package [Intl_translation](https://pub.dev/packages/intl_translation) can handle multiple arb source files since [0.17.5](https://pub.dev/packages/intl_translation/changelog):

> Allow multiple ARB files with the same locale and combine their translations.

Answer (score 0):

[This project](https://github.com/okellogerald/l10n/tree/master) may be of help.

It might be a drawback to some that it uses the go-language to generate localisation files.

It follows the flutter_localizations style, in how the translations are written and documented as well as the generated files.

The added advantage is that it supports grouping of localizations not only by the folders but also supports grouping by feature (or whatever you would like to group the localizations by) so that they can be referenced as follows: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.profile.name

Check out [this example](https://github.com/okellogerald/l10n/tree/master/example) for more information on how this works.

I hope it helps.